# Convert blackerry program/app into an installable form

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

I need to send a completed BlackBerry app, for OS 5, to my client in an installable form. What are the ways to achieve this?

I am using the BlackBerry Eclipse plugin and I have a BlackBerry Bold 9000.

Comment: I did by following link:http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/load-an-application-onto-your-blackberry.html

Answer (score 0):

## Follow this steps:

1)  To get Signing Keys you will need to go to the BlackBerry Developer’s web site:
https://www.blackberry.com/SignedKeys/

2)  As you finished your registration successfully you will get the confirmation mail with the order number. 
3)  You will get three different mail(Within 48 hours or within 2 working days) from the devsupport@rim.com which contains
client-RBB-XXXXXXXXX.csi
client-RCR-XXXXXXXXX.csi
client-RRT-XXXXXXXXX.csi
Where “XXXXXXXXX” may be any number.

4)  You can configure these .csi files in this ways.
Configure using Eclipse IDE 
i.  Go to windows > preferences > BlackBerry  Java Plug-in > Signature Tool > Install New Key
ii. Please select client-RBB-XXXXXXXXX.csi file which you get from RIM.
iii.    You will get the pop up window which ask for password and configure password. Please enter eight digit number which you what to set as you password. And remember it for future use.

iv. After clicking ok button you will get a screen which generates the random information. Please drag your mouse over that screen(Continuously until whole process will be finished) to proceed further.
v.  After finishing random info. Generation you will be asked to enter the registration PIN. Please enter same Registration PIN as you applied for Registration.
vi. You will get the success message.
vii.    Follows steps (ii) to (v) for client-RCR-XXXXXXXXX.csi & client-RRT-XXXXXXXXX.csi files (Those files that you received from BB server).
5)  After finishing the registration process, you are able to sign you BB app. Open the Eclipse, select project that you want to sign, goto “Project-> Blackberry -> Sign With Signature Tool…” Enter the 8 digit password which you entered in step (iii) when following popup screen appears and click on ok.
Note:
 Please take back up of “sigtool.csk” & “sigtool.db” from “eclipse\plugins\net.rim.ejde\vmTools” to use the key in case of reinstallation of Eclipse/Blackberry SDK.

after that sign the application using key.

and you can find the ".cod" & ".alx" file in deliverable folder , you can send it to the client..